# How to initialize context?

Tags: android, android-context

This is a really stupid question but what do I set context equal to in Context context = ...

Just declaring it sets it to null and I need to use context for my app.

Comment: You need to provide some more context (no pun intended). This question is unanswerable in its current form; we cannot see your code nor your implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot instantiate a Context object. This is controlled by the system.  However,  every Application has a Context and every Activity is a Context,  so you have a couple of was to obtain a pointer to a Context object:

1. Assign a pointer to an Activity object to the Context object pointer (i.e.  Using the this keyword)
2. The Activity class has a method called getApplicationContext() which retrieves a pointer to the Context object contained by the Application.